# How to get all string format parameters

Tags: c#, .net, string, parameters, string-formatting

Is there a way to get all format parameters of a string?

I have this string: "{0} test {0} test2 {1} test3 {2:####}"
The result should be a list:
{0}
{0}
{1}
{2:####}

Is there any built in functionality in .net that supports this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't hear about such a build-in functionality but you could try this (I'm assuming your string contains standard format parameters which start with number digit):

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
string input = "{0} test {0} test2 {1} test3 {2:####}";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\{\d+[^\{\}]*\}");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    result.Add(match.Value);
}
```

it returns `{0} {0} {1} {2:####}` values in the list. For tehMick's string the result will be an empty set.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to find all the substrings matching that pattern.

A regular expression like `\{.*?\}` would probably do the trick.

Comment: Look out for escaped braces, like this: "while(true){{c++;}}" There are no format items there.

Comment: Good point. I don't actually know much about C# or the syntax of its format strings. Is it reasonable to assume that anything enclosed with a single set of braces is a format item?

Answer (score 1):

no, there is no built in feature to do this. You'd have to parse them out with a regex or something

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it.  Reflector suggests all the format string parsing happens inside StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider, string, object[]).

Answer (score 0):

To get a good starting point on finding all the curly braces you should take a look into the [FormatWith extension method](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables.aspx).